# Putting rows["tddaw"] in commas

Tags: php

So I was wondering how could I put

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT title, script_desc, banner, author, price FROM market";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "  <div class=\"item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4\">
            <div class=\"thumbnail\">
                <img class=\"group list-group-image\" src=\"http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff\" alt=\"\" />" . $row["banner"] . "/> <div class=\"caption\">
                    <h4 class=\"group inner list-group-item-heading\">" . $row["title"] . "</h4><div class=\"row\">
                    <div class=\"col-xs-12\">
                        <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-md-3\">
                            <p class=\"lead\">"
            . $row["price"] . "</div>
                        <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-md-5\">
                        0 reviews<br>
                        <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star\"></span>
                        <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star\"></span>
                        <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star\"></span>
                        <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star\"></span>
                        <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star\"></span>

                        </div>
                        <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-md-4\">
                            <a class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"scripts/example1\">" . $row["title"] . "</a>                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
";
$conn->close();

 ?>

            echo "  <div class=\"item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4\">
            <div class=\"thumbnail\">
                <img class=\"group list-group-image\" src=\"http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff\" alt=\"\" />" . $row["banner"] . "/>
```

so changing the source of `"src=\"http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff\" "` into `" src=\"$row["banner"] "`

So putting `$row["Banner"]` instead of `"src=\"http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff\"`

So basically putting rows insinde the comma's sorry for sounding noobish just started php not to long ago

Comment: Please, add code to the question text. To do this, copy and paste code, select it and press `Ctrl + k`

Comment: Also could you better explain, what you need?

Comment: When you say "commas", do you mean "quotes"?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
            <img class=\"group list-group-image\" src=\"http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff\" alt=\"\" />" . $row["banner"] . "/> <div class=\"caption\">
```

to

```
            <img class=\"group list-group-image\" src=\"" . $row["banner"] . "\" alt=\"\" />" . $row["banner"] . "/> <div class=\"caption\">
```

It's the same as the way you embedded all the other `$row` variables into the output.

BTW, if you used single quotes around the string, you wouldn't have to escape all the double quotes inside. Or you could use single quotes inside, since HTML allows either type of quote around attributes.